# Planes showing in render preview but not when rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm experiencing an issue when rendering my scene. In render preview the 'ceiling' and 'ceiling lights' are visible, but when I render, those two are missing.

I'm new to Blender and I'm using 2.8. The layers both have "Disable in renders" unchecked and I'm using Cycles.

Here is the link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAALaJJeb2UOxFH6RPAOVJtCCByFAn1MeG4opLutcf1uJsmVycv20

Appreciate any help

[image: Render preview]
[image: Rendered image]

Comment: You've likely hidden objects in the viewport (eye icon) without hiding it in the render (camera icon). That object is blocking the view on the ceiling.

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to attach blend files. This will ensure the link won't expire. Thx

Comment: Thanks Robert. This has fixed the issue :)

And thanks Bruno, I'll use that link going forward to attached files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above by Robert was right. Your **Aisle 6** (hidden in viewport but not in render) is blocking your camera. Disable Aisle 6 from render and it'll render fine.

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, working perfectly now. I've been tearing my hair out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ceiling Z:

[image: Your Ceiling Z]

Your ceiling Light Z:

[image: Your ceiling Light Z]

they are in the same position. Lower your ceiling lights Z.
you'll get with Area lights reduced...

[image: Cycles Render]